# Export all AD data via Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

I have so much AD user data, 1.5 million +, that I need to export their attributes and powershell is dying.  CSVDE does not export these properties.  help!!!

`ForEach ($fuck in "a*","b*","c*","d*","e*","f*","g*","h*","i*","j*","k*","l*","m*","n*","o*","p*","q*","r*","s*","t*","u*","v*","w*","x*","y*","z*") {Get-ADUser -Filter {(objectClass -eq user) -AND (objectCategory -eq Person) -AND (Name -like $fuck)} -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=whatever,DC=whatever,DC=com" | Export-Csv -path .\group.csv -NoType -append}`

Comment: How many domain controllers do you have in the AD? The script maybe is slower with SAM,  NAM or Asian users.  I advise to export by DC and user name in parallel.  You can merge all files later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the user base and invoke the script in iterations for these different user bases. E.g. You can first export users with name starting from a to i, then from j to p and then from q to z. You can try narrowing the users you export in one iteration even further and check if you still face the issue.